# Composer error when trying to load ZendFramework 2 skeleton app

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php

I have recently started to learn ZendFramework2 and am at the part where I need to run `php composer.phar install` to initialize the skeleton application.  I've already successfully executed the following instruction:

```
git clone git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
```

I know I have good outbound connectivity. My problem occurs when I get to the part, where I need to install the composer. I get the following output:

```
rt_zapzap@zingzing1:/var/www/ZendApp$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies
- Installing zendframework/zendframework (2.2.0rc3)
Downloading: connection...
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://api.github.com/repos/zendframework/zf2/zipball/release-2.2.0rc3" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request)



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-    installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]
```

For reference my `composer.json` looks like

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1"
    }
}
```

Any idea where I might look to correct this issue?

Comment: can you add your composer.json ?

Comment: Remi,

My composer.json is ->

{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1"
    }
}

Thanks for your reply.

James

Comment: try for the moment  **"zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.0rc3"**

Comment: I think this week the stable release of ZF2 2.2 will be out

Comment: Remi,

Still the same error but now it says ->

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://api.github.com/repos/zendframework/zf2/zipball/release-2.2.0rc3" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request)

It appears it's having a hard time finding a proper release version.  Does that seem like what you see going on?

James

Comment: me I'm using the 2.1.5 the most stable right now. you can add this too: "minimum-stability": "dev",

Comment: Remi, The version thing is EXACTLY the problem.  I've got 2.1.4 on my box and once I specified that version all happened as expected.  Thanks so much for your help.  How do I change the title of this issue to include **SOLVED** so folks will know there's a solution?

Comment: Just figured out the **SOLVED** thing.  Thanks again.